# Max level of floor upgrade?

Tags: tiny-tower

Is there a maximum level a floor can be upgraded to?

I refer to the upgrade button on each floor which cost 3 bux per level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there seems to be no limit to the number of upgrades to a floor.  However, you have to decide if its worth upgrading up that high.  The only obvious benefit of getting a lot of upgrades is if you get a big spender who'll buy up all the stock.  That's when you have a nice bux->coins exchange ratio since you can spend 35 bucks to restock a floor and sell a few hundred thousand coins worth of items.

Comment: I'm really looking to minimize my time spent restocking. My tower is complete with all floors 3 stars and almost complete 9's. I've over 3000 bux to spend and nothing obvious to spend it on! So I tend to dip in and out the game mostly playing when new floors are added.

Comment: @BarryKaye note that the more stock a shop has, the longer it'll take to restock.  But yes, you'll spend less total time restocking since they run out less often.